# How to add custom question survey on my web

Tags: web, webforms, velo, nlp-question-answering, custom-formatting

I want to add a custom questionnaire of my web for survey i am using Wix, can you suggest any particular way, My requirements are i want to add to add 20 questions and user just go through the survey and click on the right answer and submit it, then there should be a screen for adding email for the answer. answer should work like that the number of wrong answers divide by 22 and multiply by 100. like wrong answers are 4=> 4/22=ans => Ans*100=Answer  This last answer is the score of user how can i add this to my wix or any other form builder to add this custom scoring.

Answer (score 1):

Enabling Corvid Dev Mode also opens up an additional UI component for Wix (called Inputs) where you can build custom forms.

You would need to create a database collection with the questions and correct answers. This would bind to a repeater form. On submission, you could call a backend function [after save](https://www.wix.com/corvid/new-reference/wix-dataset/dynamicdataset/onaftersave) to calculate the score and store it in the forms collection table. You can then also store the user's email in the collection. You'll need to use the [update method](https://www.wix.com/corvid/new-reference/wix-data/update) after the initial save to the DB.

Wix Data also stores in a CSV style so you can review and export the results.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the easiest option would be to create a form with Google Forms. You can then put a link to this form on your Wix website.

Also, Google Forms gives you a spreadsheet of your results. On here you can write a formula to calculate the score for you.